# how to set current timestamp for every insert and update row in realm android

Tags: android, realm

I want to synchronize the android application with server. In Server i have maintained last update date through trigger as it uses SQL server but my android application uses Realm so how can i set current date time in a field whenever any row is inserted or updated. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to insert it in separate column ?
if it is then you can set currentTimeStamp value in object of Class and then insert

Comment: Yes i can but it will be very risky - as i have to do it for every insert and update manually.

Comment: can you use update query at last

Comment: I am using realm. i cannot get your suggestion.

Comment: please see my answer if it can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
    realm.beginTransaction();
    RealmResults<ModelClass> hallos =     realm.where(ModelClass.class).equalTo('name', 'hello').findAll();
    for (ModelClass object : hallos) {
        object.setTimeStamp(timestamp);
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: I want to automate this system because i don't want to do it every time i insert/update any row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RealmChangeListeners to handle all changes